# AWS Upload failures

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload

I am attempting to upload some large files to an AWS bucket, and frustratingly I keep getting failures. I will get

> Upload failed
> View details below.

at the top of the page, but there are no details below beyond "network error". And given that it fails over and over, day after day, and at various times of day, and always at around 90% complete suggests it's not really a network error. The main file I want to upload is a single ZIP file with a bunch of Autodesk installers, that runs about 10GB. Alternatively I have tried uploading the individual installers, which are all a little over 2GB each. With the same results, a network error at around 90% complete on a single, much smaller file.

Is there some limit to what I can upload? Or some way to get a more meaningful error report? What I get from AWS now is utterly useless.

I also get this message

> Clean up incomplete multipart uploadsAdd lifecycle rule Because of the
> errors/cancellation of this upload, you might be storing multipart
> uploads that can't be viewed on the console. We recommend that you
> create a bucket lifecycle rule to permanently delete incomplete
> multipart uploads.

This despite having already created a lifecycle rule. Does AWS just knee jerk provide that message? Or is this because I don't actually have the rule configured properly? The fact that I can't see the partial uploads make it a bit hard to actually KNOW if I have the rule working right. Perhaps there is a way to audit the rule that I don't know about?

Comment: Are you using your browser ? did you trying using the awscli to see if you have the same issue ? see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-services-s3-commands.html

Comment: I've started to face the same issue today. I haven't tested the CLI option yet, but changing from MS Edge (91) to Firefox (89) solved the problem